# Correct way to close down additional instances of a process?

Tags: c#, winforms, process

there a lots of different examples floating around SO using `mutex`, `Environment.Exit(0)` (Console app), `Application.Exit()` (Win forms) and lot's of post saying not to use `process.kill()`.

Could someone explain the political incorrectness of how I am closing OTHER instances of my application.  It is a windows forms app.  This appears to be working perfectly on my local environment, but I am scared that there are some robust issues I am not aware of.

```
    // I get the current process name and ID
    string currentProcName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;
    int currentProcID = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;

    // I then get a list of all process running under this name
    Process[] currentProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName(currentProcName);

    foreach (Process proc in currentProcess)
    {
        // if the found process id is using the same name, but not this current id, kill it.
        if (proc.Id != currentProcID)
        {

            proc.Kill(); // Documentation says it imediatly stops the associated process.
            proc.Close(); // Documentation says that it frees all resources associated with this component

        }
    }
```

As per documentation, I would think this is a reasonable way to close OTHER instances of the running application.  Could some more experienced point out some issues if their is any? Aside from atomicity, as I will add in exception handling.

Comment: Well, part of it comes down to knowing what the other process is doing, and if it's possible or likely to be in the middle of something that needs to be finished.  That's why it's not good to suggest solutions like this to a wide audience as *the* solution.  If you know that, in your case, there's no persistent data left in an inconsistent state, or anything along those lines, it's *possible* that this is acceptable in your circumstances.

Comment: Is the goal of this to run a single-instance of the application?  Under what conditions do you wish to kill other sister processes?

Comment: Thanks for the clearance Servy. @JohnArlen I am creating a c# executable for an unmanaged native application and I would like to allow the native app to run the program in debug mode or run mode (one would show the program interface, the other hides everything)by calling the exe from the native language passing it a "Debug" or "Run" command arguement.  This scenario comes into place when I want to kill the previous version of the win forms application via opening another instance.  It does work great on my testing environment but we all know that can change!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must defer to Raymond Chen here for reference:

- [Why can't you trap TerminateProcess?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/22/191123.aspx)
- [Further discussion on Killing a process vs. closing it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/23/192531.aspx)

Closing a process in a cooperative manner is by far the *best* way to get rid of it: It allows for the proper shutdown/closing to occur. Killing a process basically calls `TerminateProcess`, which flat-out **stops** whatever it is doing and kills the bugger.